# Managing remote tomcat instances using hawtio

Tags: tomcat, hawtio

We have 1 single tomcat instance each deployed on 5 different physical systems.  I would like to manage all these tomcat instances using 1 single hawtio application.  Can anyone please guide me with the right approach?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

A bit short but its in rough strokes like this:

You can install jolokia (or hawtio which has jolokia included) on each of those 5 tomcat servers. Then you can use hawtio to remote manage these JVMs, using the jvm plugin, where you can specify the hostname, port and context path to access jolokia.